# Выбор WYSIWYG-редактора

Tags: wysiwyg

Два условия: русскоязычность и возможность установить изначальный цвет фона редактора и изначальный цвет текста. Или подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать в elrte. Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TinyMCE - взять да подключить свои стили страницы.

Comment: А там можно будет не просто константу, а значение из бд MySQL?

Comment: Так почему бы не передать значение из mysql в переменную js? в чем сложности?

Comment: Спасибо за внимание к моему вопросу, поставлю правильный ответ, но разобрался сам(хотел сначала в elrte попробовать).  
Там зашёл в elrte.min.js, нашёл строку в которой создаётся сам документ-рабочая область редактораб и добавил туда строку <link rel=\'stylesheet\' type=\'text/css\' href=\'/../../css/elrte.php\' />    
В эти стили и просписал, что мне надо.

Comment: Очень хорошо, что сами нашли решение!